# How to configure MessageCodesResolver for spring custom validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-validator

I try make validation for data object which can be represented with `json` in next way:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "mail": "mail@ukr.net",
  "map": {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  },
  "name": "string",
  "secondLevel": {
    "id": "string",
    "mail": "mail2@ukr.net",
    "phone": "string"
  }
}
```

`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation` provides me a lot of solutions out the box. To make some configurations for specific messages I applied `messages.properties` and added

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(MessageSource messageSource) {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return bean;
    }
```

This solution applies to spring annotations which expands jsr-303. So messages loaded from properties file and detected by codes.

Next step is to cover my need with `map` field validation (it can have different properties. Rules might also be different depending on identifier). So very common `validator` for that is:

```
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Component
public class FirstLevelValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FirstLevel.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        FirstLevel first = (FirstLevel) target;
        @NotNull Map<String, String> map = first.getMap();
        if (map != null) {
            if (!map.containsKey("key1")) {
                errors.rejectValue("map", "mandatory.parameter", "\"key1\" field is required.");
            }
            if (!map.containsKey("key2")) {
                errors.rejectValue("map", "{mandatory.parameter2}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The custom validator works if one is registered in `WebDataBinder`.
To make working message loading by codes for it I need to configure `MessageCodesResolver` for the `binder`.

### Question is:

How to configure `MessageCodesResolver` for my scenario?
Is it possible to share `messageSource` for the resolver?
...last step should be `binder.setMessageCodesResolver(messageCodesResolver)` I hope.

### P.S.

`mandatory.parameter` and `mandatory.parameter2` located in `messages.properties` file:

```
mandatory.parameter=Required.
mandatory.parameter2=Required2.
```

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out? I have the same problem...

Comment: I didn't. I used some ugly workaround, because this is not urgent part for my project